# Angular 6 - How to disable all buttons excluding clicked button

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular6, angular-forms

I have been using Angular for a couple of weeks now and it's starting to make sense and I can mostly fix any problems I find but this one I don't know where to start. If it was JQuery, it wouldn't be a problem.

I have a form which has an edit button next to each text box.

[image]

When you click the edit button, it makes the field editable and change the buttons to save and close. It also disables all the other edit buttons until either the save or close button is clicked.

[image]

What I wanted to do is have a text box with a Bootstrap 4 class which makes the field readonly and when you click the edit button, it removes the Bootstrap class and makes it editable. I couldn't get to work so I implemented another solution which I am not happy with even though it works.

This is my HTML page which is cut down to the 2 elements show but there are more

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm">
    <div class="form-group row" *ngIf="!developerNameEdit">
        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Developer Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {{ developer.developerName }}<button (click)="editDeveloperName()" [disabled]="disabled" class="btn btn-sm btn-link" type="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row" *ngIf="developerNameEdit">
        <label for="developerName" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Developer Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" formControlName="developerName" name="developerName" class="form-control" id="developerName">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button (click)="saveDeveloperName()" class="btn btn-success" type="button"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button> 
                    <button (click)="closeDeveloperName()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row" *ngIf="!receptionPhoneEdit">
        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Reception Phone</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {{ developer.receptionPhone }}<button (click)="editReceptionPhone()" [disabled]="disabled" class="btn btn-sm btn-link" type="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row" *ngIf="receptionPhoneEdit">
        <label for="receptionPhone" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Reception Phone</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" formControlName="receptionPhone" name="receptionPhone" class="form-control" id="receptionPhone">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button (click)="saveReceptionPhone()" class="btn btn-success" type="button"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button> 
                    <button (click)="closeReceptionPhone()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

This is my component (stripped down to show important info)

```
export class DeveloperDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    developer: Developer;
  editForm: FormGroup;
  disabled: boolean = false;

  developerNameEditBtn: boolean = false;
  receptionPhoneEditBtn: boolean = false;
  // more of these for other formelements

  developerNameEdit: boolean = false;
  receptionPhoneEdit: boolean = false;
  // more of these for other formelements

  constructor() {} //other stuff in here

  ngOnInit() {}//other stuff in here

  editDeveloperName() {
    this.developerNameEdit = true;
    this.disabled = true;
  }

  saveDeveloperName() {
    this.disabled = false;
  }

  closeDeveloperName() {
    this.developerNameEdit = false;
    this.disabled = false;
  }

  editReceptionPhone() {
    this.receptionPhoneEdit = true;
    this.disabled = true;
  }

  saveReceptionPhone() {
    this.disabled = false;
  }

  closeReceptionPhone() {
    this.receptionPhoneEdit = false;
    this.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

I worked out that I need 3 functions.

1. edit
2. save
3. close

I thought about somehow passing the input element to the functions and in those function handle the disabling of the other elements etc.

Has anyone got suggestions on how to do this? Maybe links to examples that do something similar. After some research I thought about using directives but don't know where to start.

Comment: What are you trying to do? disable all the edit buttons but not the save and cancel buttons?

Comment: @BenTaliadoros. Yes. It should disable all the other edit buttons except the one clicked. Once it's clicked, hide the edit button and show the save/close

Comment: Why not disable it if its hidden? If you just disable them all and hide it it will be easier, if i understand what you want.